# setState() called in constructor: HomepageState#5ee97(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have written this code here:

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed:() async {
                    final HomepageState hs = new HomepageState();
                    Position position = await hs.getGeoLocationPosition();
                    String Address='';
                    print("position:");
                    print(position);
                    hs.GetAddressFromLatLong(position).then((String result) {
                      print("result:");
                      print(result);

                      setState(() {
                        if (result is String)
                          Address = result.toString();
                      });

                    });

                    launch('sms:+201100840233?body='+Address);
                  },
                  child:Text('Send Location'))
```

Which is supposed to use a method in the HomepageState of another .dart class to get a position object, pass it to another method in that class to obtain an Address string which will then be added to an SMS and sent. However, the text actually added to the SMS is always the initialized text "null". I suspect this has something to do with the error in the question title as it started appearing only after I wrote the `hs.GetAddressFromLatLong(position)` method. I have no idea how to solve this though. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your call to GetAddress to

```
address = await ha.getAdress…
```

Avoid uppercase for variables.

Also No need for result variable or setState()